# Filtering objects by a search

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex, mongoose

I am trying to filter a list of products by a search parameter that will check for products that have the property `name` and `seller.store.name` similar (LIKE in php) to the search parameter.

```
viewAll: async (req, res) => {
    const search = req.query.search || '';
    const user = User.find({ store.name: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } });

    const filter = search ? {
        name: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
        seller: { user }
    } : {};

    const products = await Product.find({ ...filter })
        .populate('store', 'store.name store.img');

    res.send({ products });
},
```

I am running into two problems.

1. I cannot compare the `store.name` property using the `db.collection.find` method. I am getting the error `',' expected.ts(1005)`. I have tried using both `store.name` and `store['name']`.
2. I would like the filter to be similar to the LIKE keyword in PHP and not an exact match. I'm not sure what function or options I should be using.

These are my models:

**product.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    seller: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { unitPrice: Number, unit: String, required: true },
    stock: {
        amtAvail: Number,
        amtSold: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
        required: true
    },
    active: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

**user.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isSeller: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
    store: {
        type: Object,
        name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        img: {
            profile: String,
            header: [String]
        },
        contact: {
            line: String,
            phone: Number,
            accountNumber: Number
        }
    },
    address: String,
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Any help and ideas would be greatly appreciated!